# Android Studio Linear Layout positioning not working?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a scrollable list of cardviews(which are housed in framelayouts) inside a linear layout, however the first cardview I placed was in the wrong position (I expect it to be at the top of the linear layout, but instead it appeared at the bottom) Is this a bug? How can I fix it?
here is my code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="417dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productDetails">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/history_1"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the picture:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlXYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

change the orientation to horizontal

your code should be like that

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="417dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productDetails">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"> <!-- changed from vertical to horizontal -->

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/history_1"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```